# jQuery get computed CSS value

Tags: jquery, css, attr

I have a loop which decreases the margin-top by 182px every iteration. I want to get the value of margin-top so I can tell it when to stop running but when I try run it in console, it returns "undefined" Please advise how to change this to get the real value.

Here is what I am using, I am using attr() because the value it needs to get is an inline style:

```
$marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').attr("style");
```

The rest of the code is below

```
// if statements to move carousel up
$carouselNum = $('.carousella').length;

$marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').attr("style");

if($carouselNum  > 1){
//     // function empMove, the '-=' allows the -margin-top to run every time. Without this it will set the margin-top to the same value every loop
    function empMove() { $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', '-=182')};

    setInterval(empMove, 20000);
}
else if($carousel < 1){
    // do something
}
else{
    // do something
}
```

Comment: Hi, all I tried the css("margin-top"); method first and this does return a value but it is the original value of "0px". The value I am after is an inline style hence I tried using attr.

Comment: Where do you want to use the marginTop? You may have retrieved the marginTop before it has been incremented.?

Comment: @dunli I want to use it while the loop is running. I think you may have found the answer, the people below seem to have the correct answer but the variable name returns the value before incrementation. Do you have a method running it while incrementing? Thanks :)

Comment: Have you tried putting `$marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').attr("style");` inside the `empMove()` function?

Comment: @dunli Thanks, I tried that after your first comment and it did solve the problem. Cheers

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Try this:

```
$marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top");
```

Comment: Hi, when I try that it returns "0px" not the incremented value. However when I tried $marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', ' '); it returned [<div class=​"emp-wrap" style=​"margin-top:​ -182px;​">​…​</div>​]so there it does show the incremented value but how do I access only that value? Thanks

Comment: Yes please see my comment above. Cheers

Comment: $marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top"); returns "0px"

Comment: $marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css('margin-top', ' '); returns [<div class=​"emp-wrap" style=​"margin-top:​ -182px;​">​…​</div>​]

Comment: The second version is invalid. It sets the margin-top to ''. That's not what I suggested. If what I suggested doesn't work, then I say you're not using it right.

Comment: Hi, do you know of anyway of retrieving the value from the second version, even though it may not be valid, it is still returning the correct value?

Comment: No, it is not valid and it does not return the correct value. I don't know how many different ways to explain this. The version I gave you is the right one. If it doesn't work right, then you aren't using it right. How else can I say it?

Comment: After more testing I found that your method - $('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top"); does work, but the variable name - $marginTop returns the original value when called.

Comment: Why does your variable name start with `$`? Just do `var marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top");`, and then tell me what the value of  `marginTop` is.

Comment: I found the problem, I had to move it the function empMove() in order to get the correct value.

Answer (score 0):

```
$marginTop = $('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top");
```

Comment: Hi, that only returns the original value of "0px" not the incremented value, any ideas? Thanks

Answer (score 0):

use the following

```
$('.emp-wrap').css("margin-top");
```

Additionally you could use parseInt to get the integer value only

```
parseInt($(".testclass").css("margin-top"));
```

See: http://jsfiddle.net/kEVq7/

Comment: Thanks I saw it working on your fiddle but when I use css() it only returns the original value, not the incremented value.